# Bootstrap 3 grids not displaying as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hava a Bootstrap 3 grid system as 3-6-3. The middle one, 6, is further subdivided into 6-6 and that's where my data are displayed.
I now have two grid displaying my data but not as expected. The div content on the right hand side displayed as expected but the ones
on the left display with respect to the ones on the right. I want them displayed and closely stacked as it is obtainable in www.pinterest.com. The picture below is 6 grid that was further subdivided into 6-6 grid.
[image: The picture is 6 grid that was further subdivided into 6-6]

```
<div class="container col-xs-offset-0 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class = "rows">
        <div class="col-md-3">   
            <div class = 'feeds'> 
                <p> Dynamic content goes here... 
                        but this is just one grid stacked on each other</p>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class = 'rows'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <div class='rows'>
            <!--Fetch data from Database and echo as many as the 
                        total number of rows returned-->
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <div class='alignrows'>
                        <div class = 'feeds'>
                         <p> Dynamic content goes here... 
                         Content determines the height and this is where the problem is</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "rows">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p> Dynamic content goes here... 
                   but this is just one grid stacked on each other</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.alignrows {
    position: relative;
}
.feeds {
    background-color: rgb(238,243,243);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must regroup all div into container div. [demo picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-HhAFfhRAowclgteHVhd0ZiNzU3U2c0MlNJbjlqQWxiaW1B/edit?usp=sharing).
Please try this code, it's working for me

```
.test col-md-6:nth-child(even)
{
   clear:both;
}

.k p:last-child
{
  clear:both;
}
```

example PHP code :

```
    <div class="test">
<?php
    // here Fetch data from Database 
    while(data)
    {
     echo '<div class="col-md-6"> .... </div>';
    }
?>
    </div>
```

Comment: It didn't work and I am sure this is far from the solution to my problem. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @user3009875 oki ! can you put a demo in jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a CSS3 feature called `columns`.

You may set these properties `column-count`, `column-gap`, and `column-rule` to have the  columns look differently.

You may also set different column numbers for different screen sizes using the css media selector, like so: `@media (min-width: 1100px)`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eLVLx/1/

Source: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. It only clear the top and bottom margin but it didn't let it work like Pinterest.com. I have two columns as shown in the picture and the solution you gave works for single column.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns use the CSS float model. The current result you describe is actually what is to be expected. The desired result you describe requires a more modern CSS layout model like flex or grid, but you could also slap a JavaScript library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) on to your current code.